# Difference between the equation inequalities and absolute value inequalities

Tags: inequality, education, absolute-value

Using symbol lab I put this in $|x+4|\le |2x+10|$ and the answer I get is $x \le -6$ or $x\ge -14/3$, but when I manually worked out it was $\;x \ge -6\;$  or $\;x\ge -14/3$. My working out is in the description:[The image of my working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWfN0.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I don't understand the rules which are applied to remove tha absolute values. Can you explain? (using MathJax please!)

Comment: @Bernard i have basically put into two equation one is x+4<= 2x+10 and the other to x+4<= -(2x+10)

Comment: But you have to argue according to the sign of $x+4$!

Comment: @bernard i didnt get you sorry

Comment: You didn't take into account that; for instance, $|x+4|=x+4$ **or** $-x-4$, depending on the values of $x$. Similarly for $|2x+10|$. So your second line of computation is not equivalent to the first (the given inequation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this inequation is to use the fact that, for any $A$, $|A|^2=A^2$ (this removes the absolute values), and that function $x^2$ is increasing for non-negative $x$. Thus
$$|x+4|\le |2x+10|\iff(x+4)^2\le (2x+10)^2\iff3x^2+32x+84\ge 0.$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: i had 0<= 3x^2 + 32x +84

Comment: Not in your link. If you had this, it shows the problem is reduced to a quadratic inequation, which is standard from high school.

Comment: i was thinking of doing it to

Comment: If you do it, you'll find the correct result.

Comment: i got this 0<= -4  2/3 and 0 <= -6

Comment: sorry instead of 0 its x

Comment: $x$ should be *outside* of the interval of the roots, i.e. ${}\le{}$ the smallest root or ${}\ge{}$ the greatest.

Comment: do u mean i should put it into x >= -14/3 and x<= -6

Comment: Exactly! Unrelated: please use MathJax for your formulæ.

Comment: if we can solve that using quadratic then what did i do wrong in the working out, i mean i did other question with the same approach they werent wrong

Comment: I explained in my last comment just under your question: your way to remove the absolute values is wrong. Wasn't this comment clear?

Comment: but the other questions i did, i used the same approach

Comment: When you want to remove an absolute value, either you can square, ibn which case it is removed automatically, or you have to consider different cases, which you didn't, so your results are only  *partly* correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89512/discussion-between-dev-patel-and-bernard).

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the following cases:
$$x\geq -4$$ and  $$x\geq -5$$
or $$x\geq -4$$ and $$x<-5$$
or$$x<-4$$ and $$x<-5$$
If $$x\geq -4$$ and $$x\geq -5$$ then we have to solve $$x+4\le 2(x+5)$$
Can you proceed?
The second case is not possible so you have to solve for $$-5\le x<-4$$: $$-x-4\le 2(x+5)$$ and for $$x<-5$$ you have to solve
$$-x-4\le 2(-x-5)$$

Comment: i am not getting the consideration

Comment: what i see is you have factorised the RHS but my steps will be the same and will result in 2x+10, which is the same to what i did

Comment: And the other cases?

Comment: do you mean the LHS or another x

Comment: Not another $x$ only an interval.

Comment: was i taught this wrong

Comment: Should i post you the solution?

Comment: yes and can you also tell me a technique to solve this sort of problems

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple difference:

|+4|≤|2+10| <=>  (+4)^2 ≤ (2+10)^2, as both sides are positive.

On the other hand, if  +4 ≤ 2+10 it is not necessarily true that it is equivalent to (+4)^2 ≤ (2+10)^2, as x+4 and 2x+10 can have any sign.

For example, -2 ≤ 1 is not equivalent to 4 ≤ 1.

This is the reason that you get different answers, as you are changing the condition you are giving the set of numbers that satisfy the inequality.

Comment: i am wandering how to know when to use the normal case or the case using quadratic eqaution

Comment: Unless you know the terms are positive, you dont transform it into a quadratic inequality.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Sabrosky! Could you please edit your answer to include [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? It's standard practice here, and it makes your answer both nicer-looking and easier to read.

Comment: @Sabrosky  if i have -2x i have to use quadratics and of i have +2x i can use the normal way.